# Regex to find the only first appearance of a string in URL

Tags: regex

Here I am trying to isolate the URL from /admin to the end.

```
http://localhost:3000/services?search=admin 
http://localhost:3000/admin-setting-windows 
http://localhost:3000/services/setting-segment-admin--window 
http://localhost:3000/admin?search=admin
http://localhost:3000/services/admin-setting-windows
```

The regex should only find the first appearance of /admin and should reject no.5 as the first appearance is of /services here.
It should pass for 2 and 4.

I have tried doing it like this `^[^\/]*[\/admin]`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Something like `^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\K\/admin\b`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nwNv9/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works , but I am not able to understand what [^\/]+\K does here, could you please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\K\/admin\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nwNv9/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?:\/\/` - `https://` or `http://`
- `[^\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer (a substitute for a missing infinite-width lookbehind in PCRE/Onigmo)
- `\/admin` - `/admin` text
- `\b` - a word boundary.